# Why random is giving wrong output

Tags: python, random

I wrote a program for math game which calculates score based on right answers. It will ask the user twice for the answer of a given question, if its correct it will add 10. However the score is not adding properly and I can't figure out why.

```
import random
def game():
    l = ['*','+']
    score = 0
    for _ in range(2):
        x = random.randint(1,5)
        y = random.randint(1,5)
        z = int(input("Enter the val of {} {} {} \n".format(x, random.choice(l), y)))
        if random.choice(l) == '*':
            o = x * y
        elif random.choice(l) == '+':
            o = x + y
        if z == o:
            score = score + 10
            print(score)
    return("Your score is {}".format(score))

game()
```

Comment: And what is it doing wrong?

Comment: `score is not adding`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remember your choice. Every time you call `random.choice(l)` it picks a new one:

```
import random
def game():
    l = ['*','+']
    score = 0
    for _ in range(2):
        choice = random.choice(l)
        x = random.randint(1, 5)
        y = random.randint(1, 5)
        z = int(input("Enter the val of {} {} {} \n".format(x, choice, y)))

        if choice == '*': # Here you chose something random
            o = x * y
        elif choice == '+': # and here you chose something random
            o = x + y
        if z == o:
            score = score + 10
            print(score)
    return("Your score is {}".format(score))

print(game())
```

Also, a couple recommendations:

1) I would recommend using f-strings, it reads nicer:

```
z = int(input(f"Enter the val of {x} {choice} {y} \n".))
```

2) Use more meaningful variable names instead of `x`, `y`, `z`, and `o`.

Lastly an advanced tip. If you want to make this game more generic you can use the `operator` module. Then you can easily add more operations.

```
import random
import operator

def game():
    operators = {
      '*': operator.mul,
      '+': operator.add,
      '-': operator.sub,
    }
    score = 0
    for _ in range(2):
        choice = random.choice(list(operators.keys()))
        x = random.randint(1, 5)
        y = random.randint(1, 5)
        user_answer = int(input(f"Enter the val of {x} {choice} {y} \n"))
        actual_answer = operators[choice](x, y)
        if user_answer == actual_answer:
            score = score + 10

    return("Your score is {}".format(score))

print(game())
```

Comment: if * is picked first, even if we pick any other option is picked there is below to take over

Comment: Im sorry I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Even though we are not storing the choice, the options are available with if conditions. Still why its mandatory to store the choice?

Comment: Because your if statement chose something different than what you output to the user. You outputed `+` to the user but your `if` chose `*` so your code thought the user got the wrong answer.

Comment: Thanks... u r awsm :)

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as an answer if it answered your question.

Comment: Can you tell me how you pick up the python language, i am just a beginner. I can  able to write some complex program but will stuck with this kind of issues

Comment: Just keep practicing. You are on the right track. After you think you know the language a decent amount you can always get a book for the advanced parts of the language. That helped me an insane amount. Just keep doing what you are doing and experimenting. These types of bugs arent a bad thing because now you know about them in the future.